# what to use instead of fetch.EAGER in spring data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, angular5

I'm working with spring-boot and angular5 , i have this entity in spring :

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Contrat implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private Date dateDebut ;
    private Date dateFin ;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Project")
    @JsonBackReference(value="projet-contrat")
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
    @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-contrat")
    private AppUser appUser;
}
```

A repository :

```
public interface ContratRepo extends JpaRepository<Contrat,Long> {

    public Page<Contrat> findByAppUser(@Param("userApp") AppUser userApp, Pageable pageable);

}
```

As the fetch.lazy is the default one , when i try to call the method findByAppUser i get as result :

```
{id: 1, dateDebut: 1526083200000, dateFin: 1526083200000}
```

Which is normal , what i want for my case is to load also the object 'project' that exists in the entity , but i don't wan't to use the fetch.EAGER , any solution for this goal ?

Comment: Just read the value and it will read it from the DB (is that what you are asking?), but not sure why you don't EAGER

Comment: {id: 1, dateDebut: 1526083200000, dateFin: 1526083200000} this is what i get in angular side , i want also to use the object 'project' , in fact i saw in many article that it's not good to always use the EAGER fetch , also in many stackoverflow question .

Comment: Did you try to log Hibernate queries? Because the JPA specification defines FetchType.EAGER as the default for to-one relationships. It tells Hibernate to initialize the association, when it loads the entity.

Comment: I tried using queries but always i get the same result in angular , how can i log this queries ? And excuse me i thought lazy is the default one that's why im not getting the project object . Isnt it right ?

Answer (score 1):

Your entity is one-many relationship object. If you don't use EAGER, spring data will get the object without related member object. And if you get that with `contract.getProject().getName()`, then another query will be sent to get that member.

If you log the SQL, you can see that, there will be 2 queries. But if you set the field as EAGER, there will be only 1 query. You can get improvement obviously.

But you should not use EAGER always. If in 90% of time, you just need the Contract object, but no need the project data of it. It is a waste of time to get that. Because in SQL, it will relate 2 tables and get all columns of data.

SO, you should make this decision based on your usage of this entity.

[Updated based on comment]

You can use `Query` to write your sql expression. for example, I have a method to get the entity with detail:

```
    @Query("select s from Contract s left join fetch s.project pr where s.id = ?1 ")
    Contract findOneWithDetail(Long id);
```

If I need to get the detail in ONE sql, I can use this method. If I don't need the project detail, I just use `findOne(Long id)`, which is provided interface.

And, if you just want to get some columns, you need to define a DTO, with a constructor, and write your method like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT NEW com.mypackage.dto.ContractDTO(s.id, s.name, s.status)  FROM Contract AS s WHERE s.status = ?1")
    List<ContractDTO> findDTOAllByStatus(String status);
```

Comment: Exactly , i don't need all the column always , that's why i don't want to use EAGER.  So how im supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the query in your repo method, e.g. (syntax may be wrong, just show you the idea)

```
 public interface ContratRepo extends JpaRepository<Contrat,Long> {

    @Query(query="from Contrat c left join fetch c.project " +
                  "where c.userApp = :userApp")
    public Page<Contrat> findByAppUser(@Param("userApp") AppUser userApp, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: I used this '    @Query("select c from Contrat c left join fetch c.project where c.appUser = :userApp")
' but getting error with both queries .